# What's the default implementation of Challenge for JwtBearerEvents in IdentityServer 4?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, (IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions options) =>
{
   options.JwtBearerEvents.OnChallenge = ? // What does this by default do? I can't find its source anywhere...
};
```

If someone could shine some light on this, I'll be super happy.

For some reason, after the token has been authenticated, after it has been validated, this method gets invoked, and for some reason, if I don't use `JwtBearerChallengeContext.HandleResponse()`, I always get returned a 401 Unauthorized.

Hence the question - what is the default implementation of this, so that I don't miss or mess something up when implementing my own `Challenge` (by using `OnChallenge` property), which will use `JwtBearerChallengeContext.HandleResponse()`?

This is my current implementation, without having a look at what originally is supposed to be done:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, (IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions options) =>
{
   options.JwtBearerEvents.OnChallenge = context =>
      {
         if (context.AuthenticateFailure == null && context.Error == null
          && context.ErrorDescription == null && context.ErrorUri == null)
          {
              context.HandleResponse();
          }
              return Task.CompletedTask;
      };
};
```

I can't help but worry that I might have missed something, or done something incorrectly.

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L210) out there, but it doesn't exactly show what `eventContext` itself does. I only know that it's being passed by its default implementation of the package `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation`, which cannot be an empty method (Otherwise as we saw in the above code, authentication will fail.)

Comment: did you manage to solve this ? I have similar issue..

Comment: @TjDillashaw I'll check this in the weekend and if I find anything, I'll post it as an answer. I can't remember right now.